# What are 'good' cases for subtype overloads

Tags: design, object-oriented

To explain what I mean, I'm going to give an example of a *bad* case for a subtype overload.

Let's say we have a community of people. And depending on what kind people are in our community, our community has some statistics:

(in java):

```
public class Person {...}
public class PoliceMan extends Person {...}

public class Community {
    private List<Person> people;
    private int crimeFightingIndex;
    ...
    public void add(Person p) {
        people.add(p);
    }

    public void add(PoliceMan p) {
        crimeFightingIndex++;
        people.add(p);
    }
}
```

#### Why is this bad?:

This breaks encapsulation for the `crimeFightingIndex` field, since it is up to the caller to pass a `PoliceMan` with either runtime type. Either modifying `crimeFightingIndex`, as intended, or not:

```
Person p = new PoliceMan();
community.add(p); // calls the unintended method.

PoliceMan pm = new PoliceMan();
community.add(pm); // calls the intended method.
```

#### Question:

So, if any, what are 'good' cases that use this kind of overload with a subtype. i.e. where an overload takes the ~same arguments but where one or more of them is a subtype of the original.

Comment: A classic example of *don't store calculation results* violation. If `crimeFightingIndex` is a function of the cop count, well, make it a function of the cop count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OO-subtyping ("inheritance) causes bi-directional coupling (including creating the [Fragile Base Class Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class)), makes testing harder and weakens abstraction. Since every use-case for inheritance can be replaced with composition, design-to-interfaces and other forms of polymorphism, I'd suggest there are no "good" use-cases for such subtyping.

Answer (score 3):

At first sight I would direct you to the [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern. The Visitor pattern allows you to invoke on a particular subclass, and the subclass will call *back* on a overloaded method according to its type. It allows you to perform *double-dispatch*, or determine behaviour based on the types of two objects (as opposed to a single polymorphic call)

See the Wikipedia link above, and in particular note the code sample:

```
public:
    // Declare overloads for each kind of a file to dispatch
    virtual void dispatch(ArchivedFile &file) = 0;
    virtual void dispatch(SplitFile &file) = 0;
    virtual void dispatch(ExtractedFile &file) = 0;
```

Comment: But usually a visitor (a listener, or another form of callback receiver) does not extend a base class, but rather implements an interface, so I suppose @david-arno's answer below is closer to truth. Using a completely abstract C++ class as an interface, as you do here, makes sense, too.